# ¿Por qué esta función no devuelve ningún valor?

Tags: python, python-3.x, funciones

```
def incremento_porcentaje(valor_inicial, valor_final):

  return 100*(valor_final - valor_inicial)/valor_inicial#calcula en que porcentaje se incremento

def incremento_porcentaje(1000,1435)
#cuando la invoco no funciona
```

---

edito tras el comentario recibido: gracias por lo de quitar `def`. eso me soluciona el error en el output pero ahora el problema es que la función no me da ningún ouput.

Comment: La llamada a la función, no debe tener el `def`, esta es una palabra reservada para definir la función no para invocarla, haz algo así: `incremento_porcentaje(1000,1435)`

Comment: El output te lo da seguramente, el tema es que no lo estás imprimiendo, por ej: `print(incremento_porcentaje(1000,1435))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto debería funcionarte:

```
def incremento_porcentaje(valor_inicial, valor_final):
  return (100*(valor_final - valor_inicial)/valor_inicial)

var = incremento_porcentaje(1000,1435) 
print(var)
```

Concordando con el comentario, la explicación de por qué no te funciona, es esta:

Al tener return en una función, lo que haces es decirle que, cuando vas a llamar a la función, vas a almacenar lo que regrese luego de ejecutarse, cómo tú no haces eso, puse var = incremento_porcentaje(1000,1435), pero acá no termina. Tú querías que se muestre! Entonces, por eso puse print(var), luego, con var vas a poder realizar otras operaciones (en caso de haberlas) que necesites hacer con los datos generados.

Si, no vas a trabajar más con esos datos, directamente puedes poner esto:

```
def incremento_porcentaje(valor_inicial, valor_final):
  return (100*(valor_final - valor_inicial)/valor_inicial)

print(incremento_porcentaje(1000,1435))
```

Saludos!

Comment: deberias agregar una explicacion , para que se entienda y el usuario pueda tener mas nocion

Comment: Listo! Gracias por la sugerencia!

Answer (score 2):

Debes quitar el def de la ultima linea

`def incremento_porcentaje(valor_inicial, valor_final):
  return 100*(valor_final - valor_inicial)/valor_inicial#calcula en que porcentaje se incremento
  incremento_porcentaje(1000,1435) #aquí se está llamando a la función`